# Compiler error cannot find symbol in tester for investment class

Tags: java

This is my simple investment class that I have created along with a tester class. I dont know why the tester is giving me a error cannot find symbol for the tester.

```
public class Investments 
{
    // instance variables
    private double moneyInvested;
    private double investRate;
    private int numOfYears;

    double amount;
    double rate;
    int time;

    public Investments(double moneyInvested, double investRate, int numOfYears) 
    {
        this.amount = moneyInvested;
        this.rate = investRate;
        this.time = numOfYears;
    }

    public double ruleOf72() 
    {
        return (72 / this.rate/100);
    }

    public int simpleAnnual() 
    {
        return Math.round(this.amount * Math.pow(1 + this.rate/100, this.time));
    }

    public int compoundAnnual() 
    {
        return Math.round(this.amount * Math.pow((1 + this.rate/100) ^ this.time));
    }

}
```

Tester:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InvestmentsTester
{  
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How much money do you plan on investing?");
    double moneyInvested = scanner.nextDouble(); 

    System.out.println("How many years do you plan to invest this money?");
    int numOfYears = scanner.nextInt(); 

    System.out.println("At what percent rate would you like to invest?");
    double investRate = scanner.nextDouble(); 

    System.out.println("At a " + investRate + "% annual interest rate it would take you" + ruleOf72 + "years for your investments to double");
    System.out.println("Your simple annual interest after " + numOfYears + "years, with a initial investment of" + moneyInvested + "at" + investRate + "% will be worth:" + simpleAnnual);
    System.out.println("Your compound annual interest after " + numOfYears + "years, with a initial investment of" + moneyInvested + "at" + investRate + "% will be worth:" + compoundAnnual);
   }

}
```

Comment: In the main method, where is `ruleOf72` declared? You should really look into what `cannot find symbol` means.

Answer (score 0):

`ruleOf72()`,`simpleAnnual()` and `compoundAnnual()` are methods of `Investments`, you cannot call them  as variables in your main method.
You should write the tester like this:

```
public class InvestmentsTester
{  
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How much money do you plan on investing?");
        double moneyInvested = scanner.nextDouble(); 

        System.out.println("How many years do you plan to invest this money?");
        int numOfYears = scanner.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println("At what percent rate would you like to invest?");
        double investRate = scanner.nextDouble(); 

        Investments inverstment = new Investments(moneyInvested , numOfYears , investRate ); //You should new an Investments object. Import Investments.
        System.out.println("At a " + investRate + "% annual interest rate it would take you" + inverstment.ruleOf72() + "years for your investments to double"); //call ruleOf72()
        System.out.println("Your simple annual interest after " + numOfYears + "years, with a initial investment of" + moneyInvested + "at" + investRate + "% will be worth:" + inverstment.simpleAnnual());
        System.out.println("Your compound annual interest after " + numOfYears + "years, with a initial investment of" + moneyInvested + "at" + investRate + "% will be worth:" + inverstment.compoundAnnual());
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Investments object and then call ruleOf72 from it's object.

Ex:

```
Investments i = new Investments(moneyInvested, investRate, numOfYears);
```

then call
    i.ruleOf72()